# Regex to match linebreaks not preceded by non-escaped quotes in text file

Tags: regex, python-3.3

I have a textfile where strings are enclosed by quotes `" "` and any containing quotes are escaped by `\`. I wan't to remove any linebrakes (`\n`) at in the text, as long as they are not preceded by an un-escaped quote sign (`"`), since thats the end of a line.

Here's an example:

```
"tre miljarder på att modernisera snabbtågen.\" 
Dagens mest ironiska nyhet.,Väntar på att alla Summerburst-uppdateringar snart ska dö ut   så min ångest kan släppa och jag kan återgå till ett normalt liv.,RT @mapeone: En till hashtag     på Facebook och jag badar naken i grisblod.,Dagens biologiska lektion och psykologiska  reflektion.
Så förlorade fåglarna sina penisar - DN.SE http://t.co/PFaseQMt8B,Hahaha \"@Aliceyouknow:  Hah ironiskt att jag för exakt ett år sen ville gräva ner mig lika mycket som jag vill nu   med.\" #livet,Det är bara kvinnor som på riktigt förstår paniken i om Zlatans hår skulle    försvinna. #ikon,@nellie_lind ah han har ju rakat sidorna, snart ryker väl hela skiten,Alltså    Zlatan ge fan i att mecka med håret.,Jag har ett jobb. Hur tungt är inte det. #tungt"
```

The regex pattern I've come up with so far looks like this:

```
[^"]\n+
```

But it also matches the character before the `\n`, e.g. the quote at the end of `"snabbtågen.\"` on line 1 and dot (`.`) after `"reflektion"` on line 2.

I want it to match a `\n` preceded by anything else than a non escaped `"`, but not include what's preceding it. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion

```
>>> print s
'first line'
'hello world
again'
>>> s2 = re.sub(r"(?<!')\s+", " ", s)
>>> print s2
'first line'
'hello world again'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And especially for the link! This get's me so much forward in my learning!! :-)